# SSL_Read() returns SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN but ERR_get_error() is 0

Tags: c++, sockets, ssl, websocket, openssl

I am writing a non-blocking Websocket client and using OpenSSL for the TLS layer. I am able to connect to the remote server, complete the TLS handshake, send an Upgrade request, get an upgrade confirmed response, and get an actual websocket response afterwards before the TLS layer disconnects with a `SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN`.

`SSL_get_error(...)` returns: `6 // SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN`

`ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), nullptr)` returns: `error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0)`

From my understanding, `ERR_get_error()` should pop off and return the first error on the error queue, and `SSL_get_error()` returns the last error of a `SSL_*` function. I do not understand why `SSL_get_error()` would return an error value but `ERR_get_error()` does not. According to this previous [Stack Overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18179128/how-to-manage-the-error-queue-in-openssl-ssl-get-error-and-err-get-error), `SSL_get_error()` does NOT call `ERR_get_error()`.

Following code gets called repeatedly (since it is a non-blocking socket) :

```
ERR_clear_error();
int ret = SSL_read(...);
if (ret > 0) {
  // read bytes from socket
} else {
  int err_code = SSL_get_error(ssl_session_, ret);
  if (err_code == SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN || err_code == SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL || err_code == SSL_ERROR_SSL) {
    sprintf("Disconnected: %d %s", err_code, ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), nullptr));
    // Disconnect Code
  }
}
```

I have two questions:

1. Why am I not getting an error value for ERR_get_error()?
2. Why am I getting disconnected so quickly after establishing a TLS and Websocket session?

**EDIT 1**

I used wireshark to capture the packets between the client and the server. I confirmed that the TLS handshake, the websocket upgrade, and an initial server response are successful. I noticed after the initial server response, my client gets an `Encrypted Alert 21` from the server which I believe is a fatal error and explains why the TLS session terminates immediately and my SSL error queue is empty (while it is probably a client side issue, I don't think it's the result of a recent action), and kind of explains the `SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN` value I am getting after the `SSL_Read`.

I am not sure what the `Encrypted Alert 21` entails. It might be the cert I am using (self signed). Need to investigate further.

Comment: A zero return from the underlying `recv` call is a valid return value, and not considered an error.

Comment: according to the documentation for [SSL_Read](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/ssl/SSL_read.html), any return value 0 or below indicates that the read operation was not successful: _The read operation was not successful, because either the connection was closed, an error occurred or action must be taken by the calling process._

Comment: Check the documentation for `SSL_get_error` regarding `SSL_ERR_ZERO_RETURN`.

Comment: the documentation is very sparse and vague on `SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN`: _The TLS/SSL connection has been closed. If the protocol version is SSL 3.0 or higher, this result code is returned only if a closure alert has occurred in the protocol, i.e. if the connection has been closed cleanly. Note that in this case SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN does not necessarily indicate that the underlying transport has been closed._

Comment: The last sentence just means you probably still have to close with `SSL_shutdown`.

Comment: @jxh I've updated the post. I receive a fatal error from the server which automatically terminates the connection. I need to figure out why the server is sending that error.

Comment: You probably need to install a handshake callback and debug from there.

Comment: @jxh can you clarify what you mean by a handshake callback? Are you talking about [SSL_CTX_set_info_callback](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/SSL_CTX_set_info_callback.html)? The `Encrypted Alert 21` occurs post-handshake after I have established a WSS session and received a response from the server. I believe the callback specified only triggers on handshake completion which is way before when this error occurs.

Comment: I associate alerts with handshake alerts, apologies.  Since the alert is encrypted, you will have to acquire a packet capture with private keys so you can decrypt the traffic inside wireshark. https://superuser.com/questions/1029094/tls-and-alert-21-after-handshake

Comment: If I was forced to guess, the alert is actually an indication that the server side closed the socket without calling `SSL_shutdown`.

Comment: Yes, it is definitely from the server side, but this is supposed to be a websocket connection and fairly persistent. It is strange that the server would shut down the connection after serving a response on a WSS feed.

Comment: I had this issue also, SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN after SSL handshake complete.  In my case it was because the remote server, belonging to a trading exchange, had not whitelisted my client IP address.

Answer (score 3):

Alright, the root cause of the issue has been determined but a lot of hoops were jumped through and time wasted to get there. I was able to decrypt the SSL traffic by grabbing the master key using the OpenSSL method, [SSL_SESSION_get_master_key()](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/ssl/SSL_SESSION_get_master_key.html), and the Client Hello's Random value with wireshark.

Relevant Code to output master key after SSL_Connect:

```
ERR_clear_error();
int ret = SSL_connect(ssl_ptr);
if (ret > 0) {
    SSL_SESSION * ssl_session = SSL_get_session(ssl_ptr);
    if(ssl_session != NULL) {
      unsigned char master_key_buf[256];
      size_t outlen = sizeof(master_key_buf);
      size_t buf_size = SSL_SESSION_get_master_key(ssl_session, master_key_buf, outlen);
      if(outlen > 0) {
        char hex_encoded_master_buf[513];
        // hex encode the master key
        for(size_t i = 0; i < buf_size; ++i) {
          sprintf(&hex_encoded_master_buf[2*i], "%02x", master_key_buf[i]);
        }
        hex_encoded_master_buf[(2*buf_size)] = '\0';
        // log out the hex-encoded master key in master buf here
      } 
    }
}
```

Using the [NSS Key Log CLIENT_RANDOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/NSS/Key_Log_Format) format in wireshark to decrypt the captured SSL Traffic, I was able to examine the aforementioned `Encrypted Alert 21` which ended up just being a WebSocket FIN and close_notify.

It turns out, the underlying reason was that during the handshake, my WSS Upgrade Request message did indeed containing the right headers, but I was actually sending a garbage payload with it. It was a case of setting the size using `sizeof` of the message buffer instead of `strlen` when sending the message. The server would have parsed the Upgrade message just fine and completed the handshake successfully, but the next time it checked its socket, it would read in garbage when it was expecting a WSS message. This caused the abrupt closure of the websocket connection.

**In Summary, to answer my original two questions:**

1. Why am I not getting an error value for ERR_get_error()?

The connection is being terminated on the server side, and the error queue would contain errors on the client side, which there are not any, at least on the SSL/TLS layer.

2. Why am I getting disconnected so quickly after establishing a TLS and Websocket session?

My Initial Upgrade request contained a valid Websocket Upgrade Request with Garbage Data following it. The Server parsed the Websocket Upgrade Request and confirmed the upgrade, and started sending back data. The next time the server checked its socket, it still had the garbage values that was sent with the original Websocket Upgrade Request. Since the server did not recognize it as a valid Websocket message, or anything else for that matter, it decided to terminate the connection with a `close_notify`.

Comment: 1. The issue here remains that if you got the zero return there was no error, only a disconnect, which is not an error, so calling `ERR_get_error()` wasn't valid. The *reason for the disconnect* was ultimately the `sizeof` error.